# Firefox Addon Does not Recognize extension.getBackgroundPage()

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a quick question, I ported a Chrome Extension to Firefox and all seems to be working fine other than when I call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` from `popup.js` it gives me the `TypeError` - I also tried the keyword `browser` instead of `chrome` such as `browser.extension.getBackgroundPage()` I still get the same error

> TypeError: browser.runtime.getBackgroundPage is not a function

The full error is the following

> TypeError: browser.runtime.getBackgroundPage is not a function[Learn
>   More] popup.js:142:5 
>    moz-extension://326d52a1-ea8a-4aa2-8845-10bfb334a761/popup.js:142:5   j

I am trying to access the function as following from `popup.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var myFucn = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); // Error at this line
});
```

Where the extension works perfectly fine in Chrome, Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK that's a bug/quirk in Firefox private mode. You'll have to use messaging.

Comment: Yes I read about it but I am not using private mode

Comment: Well, messaging is your only solution - I've encountered this bug long time ago and they still haven't fixed it.

Comment: Damn, that's really sad, I recently added some new features which require background function to called from popup.js which worked in chrome so I assumed it will work in Firefox but oh well... Thanks for letting me know though :(